# Loading events on init with fullcalendar 4 and angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I had updated the fullcalendar from v3 to v4 and I am using it with angular 8.
The problem is how to load events on `init` and `date change`.

I have tryied with this settings:

```html
<full-calendar
        #calendar
        [defaultView]="'timeGridWeek'"
        [plugins]="calendarPlugins"
        [header]="calendarHeader"
        [allDaySlot]="false"
        [slotEventOverlap]="true"
        [editable]="true"
        [selectable]="true"
        [slotLabelFormat]="'HH:mm'"
        [timeZone]="'local'"
        [nowIndicator]="true"
        [aspectRatio]="1"
        [eventTimeFormat]="'HH:mm'"
        [height]="'parent'"
        [firstDay]="1"
        [buttonText]="buttonText"
        [minTime]="'06:00'"
        [maxTime]="'23:00'"
        [views]="views"
        [events]="calendarEvents"
        [weekends]="false"
></full-calendar>
```

The component gets the events in `[events]` and it expects array. I can load array on init of the component, but I dont know how to load new events when date changes (you click the button for next week).

In fullcalendar V3 I loaded events like this:

```
settings = {
...
   events: function(start, end, timezone, callback) {
     this.callBaclend(start, end)
     .subscribe(resultData=>{
        callback(resultData);
     })
   }
...
}
```

This function triggered every time date or view changed and for bonus there is `start` and `end`. How can I make similar call in V4 with angular? I am looking through documentation but  can't find a solution.

Comment: "The component gets the events in [events] and it expects array" ...does it? I would have expected that it will accept any valid event source - array, URL, function, or event source object which is [accepted by fullCalendar itself](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-source). The [angular component documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/angular) specifically says "The <FullCalendar> component is equipped with all of FullCalendar’s options! Just pass them in as properties". Have you actually tried to define a dynamic event source and encountered a specific issue?

Comment: In this post, I have used, fullcalendar in angular 8 with the help you jquery. You can easily add dynamic events.
https://therichpost.com/how-to-implement-fullcalendar-in-angular-8

Answer (score 0):

In your example, keep this html the same:

```
<full-calendar
        #calendar
        [defaultView]="'timeGridWeek'"
        [plugins]="calendarPlugins"
        [header]="calendarHeader"
        [allDaySlot]="false"
        [slotEventOverlap]="true"
        [editable]="true"
        [selectable]="true"
        [slotLabelFormat]="'HH:mm'"
        [timeZone]="'local'"
        [nowIndicator]="true"
        [aspectRatio]="1"
        [eventTimeFormat]="'HH:mm'"
        [height]="'parent'"
        [firstDay]="1"
        [buttonText]="buttonText"
        [minTime]="'06:00'"
        [maxTime]="'23:00'"
        [views]="views"
        [events]="calendarEvents"
        [weekends]="false"
></full-calendar>
```

Then in your corresponding .ts file, define `calendarEvents` as a function:

```
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {

  ...

  constructor() {}

  ...

  calendarEvents = (dates, callback) => {
    console.log('Fetch events for dates:', dates.start, dates.end);

    this.callBackend(dates.start, dates.end)
       .subscribe(resultData => {
         callback(resultData);
       })
  };
}
```